# CSS In-line menu

Tags: html, css

What code do I need to change from the following css to make the menu near each other not underneath each other:

```
/* =Menu
----------------------------------------------- */

.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.main-navigation:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    position: relative;
}
.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    background: #e9e0d1;
    border: 1px solid rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.1 );
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
        top: 1.2em;
        left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul a {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    width: 200px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
}
.main-navigation li:hover > a,
.main-navigation li.current_page_item a,
.main-navigation li.current-menu-item a,
.main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
    color: #33605a;
}
.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a {
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/* Small menu */
.menu-toggle {
    color: #7c948a;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-small-navigation .menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Already tried changing from displya block to inline but that just reduced the padding between the  menu items

This is just a theme taken from themeshaper. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zA7Zc/) includes all code.

Comment: Could you provide the HTML structure you're using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zA7Zc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one of the following (I'm guessing that your main nav `ul` is a direct child of the `.main-navigation` container)

```
.main-navigation > ul {overflow:auto;}
.main-navigation > ul > li { float:left; }
```

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/zA7Zc/2/)

or

```
.main-navigation > ul > li {display:inline-block;}
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/zA7Zc/1/)

Edit - having seen your fiddle you need to use

```
.main-navigation .menu > ul > li
```

Comment: see example links above, new styles at bottom of style bit in fiddle